# not receiving form emails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried earlier with no solution, so I'm adding all my code to try and resolve this issue. I am not getting this form in my inbox, but my ajax function is working like it should. I have godaddy hosting, and am running it locally on wampp for mac. I've tried multiple different email addresses with no avail. I don't want to use php mailer. I just want this to function properly instead of what it seems to be doing which is shooting emails into outter space

html

```
<div class="block">
<div class="done">
<h1>Thank you! I have received your message.</h1>
</div>
<div class="form">
<form method="post" action="scripts/process.php">
<input name="name" class="text" placeholder="Name" type="text" /> 
<input name="email" class="text" placeholder="Email" type="text" /> 
<textarea name="comment" class="text textarea" placeholder="Comment"></textarea> 
<input name="submit" value="Let's Go!" id="submit" type="submit" />
<div class="loading"></div>
</form></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

jquery validation and ajax

```
$('#submit').click(function () {        

        //Get the data from all the fields
        var name = $('input[name=name]');
        var email = $('input[name=email]');
        var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]');
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
        var emailVal = email.val();
        //Simple validation to make sure user entered something
        //If error found, add hightlight class to the text field
        if (!emailReg.test(emailVal)){
        email.addClass('hightlight');
        return false;
        } else email.removeClass('hightlight');

        if (name.val()=='') {
            name.addClass('hightlight');

        }else{name.removeClass('hightlight');}
        if (email.val()=='') {
            email.addClass('hightlight');

        }else{email.removeClass('hightlight');}
        if (comment.val()=='') {
            comment.addClass('hightlight');
        }else{email.removeClass('hightlight');}

        if (name.val()=='' || email.val()=='' || comment.val()=='') {
            return false;
            }



        //organize the data properly
        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&website='
        + website.val() + '&comment='  + encodeURIComponent(comment.val());

        //disabled all the text fields
        $('.text').attr('disabled','true');

        //show the loading sign
        $('.loading').show();

        //start the ajax
        $.ajax({
            //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
            url: "scripts/process.php",                
            //GET method is used
            type: "GET",
            //pass the data            
            data: data,                    
            //Do not cache the page
            cache: false,
            //success
            success: function (html) {                
                //if process.php returned 1/true (send mail success)
                if (html==1) {                    
                    //hide the form
                    $('.form').fadeOut('slow');                    
                    //show the success message
                    $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
                //if process.php returned 0/false (send mail failed)
                } else alert('Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later.');                
            }        
        });

        //cancel the submit button default behaviours
        return false;
    });
```

and the php which I regret to say I know very little about for now

```
<?php
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$comment = ($_GET['comment']) ?$_GET['comment'] : $_POST['comment'];
//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;
//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, 
//you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your name.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$comment) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your comment.'; 
//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {
    //recipient - change this to your name and email
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';    
    //sender
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'Comment from ' . $name;    
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Comment</td><td>' . nl2br($comment) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';
    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        if ($result) echo 'Thank you! Matt has received your message.';
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

    //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
    //ajax script can react accordingly
    //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo $result;    
    }
//if the errors array has values
} else {
    //display the errors message
    for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
    echo '<a href="form.php">Back</a>';
    exit;
}
//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: How is it not working? You're getting that "sorry can't send" message? or PHP mail() succeeds but you never get the message? If it succeeds, then you'll have to check the mail server logs to see what happened to the mail. Once PHP mail() hands off the email to the server, PHP is **DONE** with the process and cannot see what happens afterwards.

Comment: Have you configured email settings while your are trying to send mail from localhost

Comment: have you checked your spam folder? the problem with godaddys shared plans is...well they are shared so loads of people are using the same ip. chances are your server's ip is on the spam lists

Comment: not in my spam folder, not getting error message, and ajax is being passed back '1' so i know the form is being processed

Answer (score 1):

There are so many issues on sending PHP mails to different mail servers. For example, when I want to send email to GMail hosts I never include `\r` for new lines and I only go with `\n`. Maybe your problem is with your headers, I place my code here and see what you can get:

```
function send($address, $subject, $content, $from = '', $html = FALSE, $encoding = 'utf-8')
    {
      if(empty($address) || empty($content)) return;

      $headers = "";

      if($from != '')
      {
        $headers .= "From: {$from}\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: {$from}\n";
      }

      $headers .= "To: {$address}\n";

      if($html)
      {
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset={$encoding}\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
      }

      $headers .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n";
      $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\n";
      $headers .= "Importance: High\n";
      $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

      set_time_limit(30);

      mail($address, $subject, $content, $headers);
    }

send('myemail@myhost.com', 'title', 'content', 'myemail <myemail@myhost.com>', FALSE);
```

Comment: Sorry that i'm such a noob with php, but this function doesn't seem to fit in. Where do i return 1 or 0?

Comment: @user1873632 As you did in your own function. Returning result is not the real problem here though you might want to check your headers. I just put this code to give you a heads up since the email seems to be sending, but with an improper formation.

Comment: I tried to answer this issue for this person in another thread, but the reality is this seems like an issue with GoDaddy hosting.  He/She's not sending the message from his domain name, likely, and accepting user input to set the mail `From:` header.  **GoDaddy doesn't allow this**

There are plenty of forum posts on the GoDaddy hosting forums which is where I think this question belongs now since they can provide the support: http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/php-mail-problems-2/

Comment: @ThomasFarvour Thanks for the information. This would be defiantly a good reminder for Googlers!